# Detecting/Tracking changes in Text Editor via Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have implemented a text editor in a page. I am displaying some text (each segment/line is enclosed in p tag) from the database in the text editor. What I want to do is when somebody makes changes to the text like adding new line, modifying an old line or deleting a line I want to retrieve that line and update it in the database. I need the line position (so I can insert/replace that line after some operations on it) and status (insert/delete/modify) so I can do some operations on that line and then store it back in DB. I tried doing it on server/backend (php) side but was unsuccessful. What I did was to get the old text and the new text (after inserting/delete/modify) and splitting them on p tag so I get the number of lines, then compare with old text (also split on p tag). The problem with that was I was unable to distinguish between new lines and modify leading to duplication of lines. I am at a dead end now, any help will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Looks you are looking for collabrative editing.. you must go with socket.io it is not small logic...  if you have something alreay implemented anyting paste here..

Comment: its not collaborative editing, the idea is , i have paragraphs stored in db in different languages. i want to retrieve lets say for english, and edit the text/content i want to get the modified/new/deleted line and update the other languages according to that.